# ¿Cómo referenciar un elemento en un grupo, para seleccionarlo individualmente?

Tags: html, jquery

> Tengo 4 tarjetas (coloco ejemplo con 2) y cada tarjeta tiene un botón. La cosa es que al hacer click en cualquier botón se dan vuelta las 4 tarjetas en simultaneo. Yo quisiera que cada botón gire su tarjeta correspondiente. Imagino que debo solucionarlo usando `this`, pero no se como referenciarlo en este caso. Alguna sugerencia?

Entiendo que dentro de la función, la palabra `this` estaría referenciando a `.okreni`, yo quisiera saber como referenciar a la `.uk-card` puntual con la que el usuario interactúa

```js
$('.okreni').on('click', function() {
  $('.uk-card').toggleClass('flipped');
});
```

```css
/* CARDS ROTATE */

.okreni {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 20px;
}

.uk-card {
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  transition: transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  transition: transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275), -webkit-transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: #fd6ca3 solid 2px;
  box-shadow: 8px 10px rgba(253, 108, 163, 0.5);
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.uk-card .card-face.back {
  display: none;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.uk-card .card-face {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
  background: #fff;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -o-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -o-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flipped .back {
  display: block !important;
}

.flipped .front {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- UIkit JS -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.4.2/dist/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.4.2/dist/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.4.2/dist/css/uikit.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Column -->
<div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body uk-width-1-5@m mr-4">
  <div class="front card-face uk-flex uk-flex-column">
    <h6><span class="icon-gold margin-right-10px" data-uk-icon="icon: code; ratio: 1"></span> Card 1.</h6>
  </div>
  <span class=" uk-position-top-right okreni" uk-icon="reply"></span>
  <div class="back card-face">
    <p class="uk-text-center">Hola
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- End Column -->
<!-- Column -->
<div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body uk-width-1-5@m mr-4">
  <div class="front card-face uk-flex uk-flex-column">
    <h6><span class="icon-gold margin-right-10px" data-uk-icon="icon: social; ratio: 1"></span> Card 2.</h6>

  </div>
  <span class=" uk-position-top-right okreni" uk-icon="reply"></span>
  <div class="back card-face">
    <p class="uk-text-center">Chau
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bueno, originalmente solo habia puesto el script pero algun usuario que ahora borró el comentario me pidio html y css, asi que ahi hay un ejemplo de lo que sucede. De todas maneras creo que con el script ``js`` solamente alcanzaba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como los elementos `.okreni` son hijos de elementos `.uk-card` puedes aprovechar esto para, como propusiste, efectivamente usar this en

```
$(this).parent().toggleClass('flipped');
```

De otro modo estarías haciendo referencia a todos los `.uk-card` existentes, por eso es que se dan vuelta ambos.

```js
$('.okreni').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('flipped');
});
```

```css
/* CARDS ROTATE */

.okreni {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 20px;
}

.uk-card {
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  //-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  //transition: -webkit-transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  //transition: transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  transition: transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275), -webkit-transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: #fd6ca3 solid 2px;
  box-shadow: 8px 10px rgba(253, 108, 163, 0.5);
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.uk-card .card-face.back {
  display: none;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.uk-card .card-face {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
  background: #fff;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -o-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -o-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  
}

.flipped .back {
  display: block !important;
}

.flipped .front {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- UIkit JS -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.4.2/dist/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.4.2/dist/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.4.2/dist/css/uikit.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Column -->
<div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body uk-width-1-5@m mr-4">
  <div class="front card-face uk-flex uk-flex-column">
    <h6><span class="icon-gold margin-right-10px" data-uk-icon="icon: code; ratio: 1"></span> Card 1.</h6>
  </div>
  <span class=" uk-position-top-right okreni" uk-icon="reply"></span>
  <div class="back card-face">
    <p class="uk-text-center">Hola
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- End Column -->
<!-- Column -->
<div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body uk-width-1-5@m mr-4">
  <div class="front card-face uk-flex uk-flex-column">
    <h6><span class="icon-gold margin-right-10px" data-uk-icon="icon: social; ratio: 1"></span> Card 2.</h6>

  </div>
  <span class=" uk-position-top-right okreni" uk-icon="reply"></span>
  <div class="back card-face">
    <p class="uk-text-center">Chau
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Me faltaba el .parent(), muchas gracias